# Timescales of plasma recombination and fluorescence?

Tags: plasma-physics, time-evolution, fluorescence

I am currently working on a very simple model for the radiation from electric arcs.
As both fluorescence (internal electronic transition) and plasma recombination occur, I would like to compare the timescales of these two phenomena.

I am aware that fluorescence generally takes some $10^{-8} \rightarrow 10^{-6} s$ to happen. But I have no clue of the timescales for nitrogen/oxygen plasma to recombine (electronically). I see it may depend a lot on factors such as temperature, composition, humidity and so on, but what would be your guess in this context? Would you expect recombination to happen more quickly than fluorescence?

Thank you all!